# how to convert char @"\" to Escape String \ by C#

Tags: c#, escaping

I have grabbed some data from a website.**A string which is named as urlresult in the data** is `"http:\/\/www.cnopyright.com.cn\/index.php?com=com_noticeQuery&method=wareList&optionid=1221&obligee=\u5317\u4eac\u6c83\u534e\u521b\u65b0\u79d1\u6280\u6709\u9650\u516c\u53f8&softwareType=1"`.

what I want to do is to get rid of the first three char @'\' in the string **urlresult**  above . I have tried the function below:

```
public string ConvertDataToUrl(string urlresult )
{

   var url= urlresult.Split('?')[0].Replace(@"\", "") + "?" + urlresult .Split('?')[1];


  return url

}
```

It returns `"http://www.cnopyright.com.cn/index.php?com=com_noticeQuery&method=wareList&optionid=1221&obligee=\\u5317\\u4eac\\u6c83\\u534e\\u521b\\u65b0\\u79d1\\u6280\\u6709\\u9650\\u516c\\u53f8&softwareType=1"` which is incorrect.

The correct result is  `"http://www.cnopyright.com.cn/index.php?com=com_noticeQuery&method=wareList&optionid=1221&obligee=北京沃华创新科技有限公司&softwareType=1"`

I have tried many ways,but it hasn't worked.I have no idea how to get the correct result.

Comment: urlresult.Split('?')[0] selects the first part of the string you just splitted. Try it with urlresult.Split('?')[1] maybe?

Comment: where are you seeing the backslashes? in debug?

Comment: Also, from what I can see, you have some unicode parts escaped in your URL. You can use System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape and System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode tools for decoding the escaped parts.

Comment: I am sorry for my careless.Now I have pasted the correct code.And the problem is solved by using System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape.By the way ,thanks all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape` method:

```
var input = @"\u5317\u4eac\u6c83\u534e\u521b\u65b0\u79d1\u6280\u6709\u9650\u516c\u53f8";
string escapedText = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(input);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.It solves the problem by your means.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be misled by the debugger because there's no reason that extra "\" characters should get inserted by the code you provided. Often times the debugger will show extra "\" in a quoted string so that you can tell which "\" characters are really there versus which are there to represent other special characters. I would suggest writing the string out with Debug.WriteLine or putting it in a log file. I don't think the information you provided in the question is correct.

As proof of this, I compiled and ran this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var url = @"http:\/\/www.cnopyright.com.cn\/index.php?com=com_noticeQuery&method=wareList&optionid=1221&obligee=\u5317\u4eac\u6c83\u534e\u521b\u65b0\u79d1\u6280\u6709\u9650\u516c\u53f8&softwareType=1";
   Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", url, Environment.NewLine, 
      url.Split('?')[0].Replace(@"\", "") + "?" + url.Split('?')[1]);
}
```

The output is:

```
http:\/\/www.cnopyright.com.cn\/index.php?com=com_noticeQuery&method=wareList&optionid=1221&obligee=\u5317\u4eac\u6c83\u534e\u521b\u65b0\u79d1\u6280\u6709\u9650\u516c\u53f8&softwareType=1
http://www.cnopyright.com.cn/index.php?com=com_noticeQuery&method=wareList&optionid=1221&obligee=\u5317\u4eac\u6c83\u534e\u521b\u65b0\u79d1\u6280\u6709\u9650\u516c\u53f8&softwareType=1
```

Comment: I understand what you mean.Actually,it responses    ["5","\u67e5\u8be2\u6210\u529f","http:\/\/www.cnopyright.com.cn\/index.php?com=com_noticeQuery&method=wareList&optionid=1221&obligee=\u5317\u4eac\u6c83\u534e\u521b\u65b0\u79d1\u6280\u6709\u9650\u516c\u53f8&softwareType=1"]        when I sniffer package with fiddler.    Therefore, I need to parse the urlstring if I want to get the correct result.